# Eigenvectors of a 2x2 Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

How do I find what the value of $e_1^\dagger (e_1 +e_2)$ is, where $e_1 ,e_2$ are the eigenvectors of a 2x2 Hermitian matrix? I have absolutely no idea where to even start with this one so any help would be appreciated :)

I know that, for a Hermitian matrix, $H=H^\dagger$, but am not sure if this applies to the eigenvectors as well?

Thanks!

Comment: The phrase "the eigenvectors of a 2-by-2 Hermitian matrix" really doesn't make sense by itself: If $e_1$ is an eigenvector, then any nonnegative multiple is also an eigenvector. If you intend these eigenvectors to be normalized to have length $1$, then you should say so. (And if so, this will partially answer your underlying question.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes they are normalised, but I am not sure how this helps me answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, expanding the brackets gives:
$$e_1^\dagger e_1 +e_1^\dagger e_2$$
This can be written as a dot product:
$$\langle e_1 ,e_1\rangle + \langle e_1 ,e_2\rangle $$
As they are an orthonormal basis, $\langle e_1 ,e_1\rangle =1$ and $\langle e_1 ,e_2\rangle =0$.
Therefore:
$$e_1^\dagger (e_1 +e_2) = 1$$

Comment: Note that “orthonormal basis” actually covers both terms: ortho- for $e_1^\dagger e_1=1$, normal for $e_1^\dagger e_2=1$.

Comment: @Semiclassical Great, thanks!