# Notation: brackets surrounding a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, notation, hermitian-matrices

I am trying to answer a question about eigenvalues of a 2x2 Hermitian matrix **H**, and am being asked to find (**H**) in terms of the two eigenvalues.

However, I am not sure what the brackets around the **H** mean, outside of normal multiplication brackets.

Thanks!

The question is worded as follows:

$\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the two distinct eigenvalues of a 2 x 2 Hermitian matrix **H**, with corresponding normalised eigenvectors $e_1$ and $e_2$. Find in terms of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$:

(i) det(**H**) -- already completed

(ii) (**H**).

Comment: Do you have a link? Is it related to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4223280/eigenvectors-of-a-2x2-hermitian-matrix?rq=1)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is a different part of the same question, but I am more confused about the notation in this case. I don't have a link but can write the question exactly as it is worded (I will edit my original question)

Comment: I see. I suspect that it is a typo and that it should be $(ii)$ ${\bf tr}(H)$, so the trace of $H$. You should be able to complete it as well.